# Store time in js

Tags: magento2, date, datetime

I need to use current store timestamp in js or phtml file, how can always have current store date-time or timestamp when phtml is cached and I cannot pass this variable to js. Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be enough to set store timezone as a variable in cached phtml and then use it to create `Date` object with correct timezone.

Comment: How i can predict summer time and other in js?